# How to create XsltListviewWebpart on Sharepoint Wepart page using visual studio?

Tags: 2013, web-part, sharepoint-server, xslt-list-view-web-part

My requirement is, I want to add one Sharepoint webpartpage in my visual studio solution, which deploys to /Pages library, where I want to show data from three different lists of same site.

After some search came across, xsltlistview webpart can help in this scenario.

Issue I am facing is, when I deploy my SharePoint farm solution, getting error of

> List does not exist.
>
> The page you selected contains a list that does not exist.  It may
>   have been deleted by another
>   user.0x81020026

After deployment viewid and list id getting change,

Any thoughts on how to create the xsltlistview webpart where on .aspx I get the listid, viewid pass it as parameter? or any other pointers ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the xsltlistviewwebpart in your .aspx page.

```
 <WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart runat="server" IsIncluded="True"
                            GhostedXslLink="main.xsl" FrameType="None" NoDefaultStyle="TRUE" ViewFlag="8"
                            Title="My Request" PageType="PAGE_NORMALVIEW" Default="FALSE"
                            __markuptype="vsattributemarkup" PartOrder="2"
                            __WebPartId="{91EB7C29-AED3-44A3-B01E-54F1893A48DC}"
                            ID="g_91eb7c29_aed3_44a3_b01e_54f1893a48dc"
                            ViewContentTypeId="0x" __designer:customxsl="fldtypes_Ratings.xsl" ListDisplayName="Your List Display Name">
```

Don't use ListID and List name parameter in this. they are always assigned new guid with deployment. Only ListDisplayName parameter will serve the purpose,

if we pass ListID parameter will give List does not exist error as Guid is different.

Hope this helps.